# how to prevent html input id duplication on asp.net mvc 3 when a model contains multiple elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that allows the user to inset multiple elements of the same type.

```
 @foreach (var gm in Model)
    {
        <tr><td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => gm.name)
        </tr></td>
    }
```

But, when I saw the generated HTML it is duplicating the id and the name

```
<tr><td>
        <input id="gm_name" name="gm.name" type="text" value="" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
        <input id="gm_name" name="gm.name" type="text" value="" />
</td></tr>
```

Is there a way to automatically add an 1,2,3,etc and the end of id, example:

```
<tr><td>
            <input id="gm_name1" name="gm.name1" type="text" value="" />
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
            <input id="gm_name2" name="gm.name2" type="text" value="" />
    </td></tr>
```

I can do that if I generate all the html, but, is there an automatically way to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using TextBoxFor, just use the [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984.aspx) method, and you can specify the name you want it to use. Something like this should work, I think:

```
 @foreach (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        var gm = Model[i];
        <tr><td>
                @Html.TextBox("gm.name" + i, gm.name, new {id = "gm_name" + i})
        </tr></td>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth you probably want.

```
<tr><td>
        <input id="gm_0__name" name="gm[0].name" type="text" value="" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
        <input id="gm_0__name" name="gm[1].name" type="text" value="" />
</td></tr>
```

It appears from the source code that the ExpressionHelper method used to translate the name from the model expression understands about array indexing expressions.  You might try something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; ++i )
{
   <tr><td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].name)
    </tr></td>
}
```

I'll confess that I haven't tried this in MVC3 so I'm not sure whether it will work or not.  In earlier versions I built this sort of thing by hand.