# In ASP.Net MVC3 how do I let .Net assign the ID of a table html element?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 display template that contains a table.  The display template will potentially get repeated on the web page.  I need to access the table via javascript to show/hide.  How can I set the ID attribute of the table html element so that it is not repeated?  I could do it manually by grabbing the ID of my Model ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080935/how-to-prevent-html-input-id-duplication-on-asp-net-mvc-3-when-a-model-contains)), but that doesn't seem as clean to me.  I'm already using a custom [html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065307/client-id-for-property-asp-net-mvc) to get html IDs for other input controls, so I'd like to follow that pattern.

Comment: How do you repeat the template in a page? If you do this within a cycle, you can add the cycle index to a const string.

Answer (score 0):

Since the html helpers dont deal with table ids, theres nothing wrong with choosing it from your model using

```
 new {id=Model.YourId}
```

as the last parameter in the html helpers.